# datagridview.Columns[""].Index doesn't work after setting new datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I programmatically added a delete button column to my datagridview and it is working fine.  But when I set the datagridview to a new datasource, the CellClick function no longer works where it prints out 0 instead of 6 which is correct value.

```
//prints out 6
    private void DataGridView_PromoList_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DataGridView_PromoList.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index);

    }


    // above function prints out 0 after this functions called
    private void cmbbxFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //probably don't need this try catch because not reloading database
        try {
            int index = cmbbxFilter.SelectedIndex;
            // Only do something if selecting different index in filter
            if (lastFilterIndex != index)
            {
                lastFilterIndex = index;
                etp.loadDisplayDT(index);
                DataGridView_PromoList.DataSource = etp.displayDT;
                Console.WriteLine("REFRESHED!");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            showAlertUser("ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString(), false);
            //.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes on the initial load it is added after data source was set.  When I reset the data source, I didn't do anything to re add the column are you saying that Winform added it to the 0 index for me?  On the GUI it looks like it is still in the same position so I am expecting it to be 6 still.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out just set DataGridView_PromoList.AutoGenerateColumns = false; when i first load the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is wise to add a delete button to every row. Consider to give every row a checkbox in a column "Delete", and a `Save` button (or OK, Apply Now) to start the delete action for all checked items.

Compare this interface with editing a text file: as long as the operator hasn't selected `Save`, he can make changes. If he doesn't want make the changes effective, simply don't press Ok.

So if the operator makes a mistake, the item is not deleted immediately. He can undo the click.

For this you need to change your DataGridviewButtonColumn to a [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn?view=net-5.0).

If you want to display a sequence of `Customers`, you'll have to create a class `DisplayedCustomers`, which aggregates `Customers` and has an extra column `IsDeleted`:

```
class Customer {...}

class DisplayedCustomer
{
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}

    // Do readonly like this:
    public int Id => this.Customer.Id;

    // changeable properties like this:
    public string Name
    {
        get => this.Customer.Name;
        set => this.Customer.Name = value;
    }

    ... // other properties

    // Add: IsDeleted
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}
```

You are already using a DataSource to display your Customers (or whatever you display). Use visual studio designer or manually change the code to something similar to this:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedCustomer.Id);
    this.columnName.DataProperyName = nameof(DisplayedCustomer.Name);
    ...
    this.columnIsDeleted.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedCustomer.IsDeleted);
}

public BindingList<DisplayedCustomer> DisplayedCustomers()
{
    get => (BindingList<DisplayedCustomer>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

public void InitCustomerDisplay()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers = this.FetchCustomersToDisplay(...);
    IEnumerable<DisplayedCustomer> customersToDisplay = customers
        .Select(customer => new DisplayedCustomer {Customer = customer});
    this.DisplayedCustomers = new BindingList<DisplayedCustomer>(
        customersToDisplay.ToList());
}
```

All Customers are displayed, there is an extra column IsDeleted. Any change that the operator makes is automatically updated in the Customer, except property IsDeleted.

Delete the Customers when the operator clicks `Ok`, or `Apply Now`:

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customersToDelete = this.DisplayedCustomers
        .Where(displayedCustomer => displayedCustomer.IsDeleted)
        .Select(displayedCustomer => displayedCustomer.Customer);

    this.DeleteCustomers(customersToDelete);
}
```

### There's room for improvement

Consider to add the IsDeleted as a column to your database table. Adjust your repository, such that for most users it fetches only the non-deleted Customers.

Change repository property:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers => dbContext.Customers;
```

into:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers => dbContext.Customers
    .Where(customer => !customer.IsDeleted);
```

This way, whenever someone accidently deletes an item, it is not really deleted, he can e-mail the superuser and ask to undelete the item. Of course the superuser has a slightly different interface to the database.

Regularly, for instance once a month, an extra process will be started to remove all items that are deleted a while ago. To do this, it might even be better to have a nullable DeleteDate column: if null, then not IsDeleted, if not null, then the extra process can use the value to to only delete items that are deleted half a year ago.